# Adding dependencies from submodule

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, exoplayer

In my project I have a submodule from exoplayer. In my `settings.gradle` I add the the lib path of the exoplayer like this

```
def modulePrefix = ":exoplayer:"
def rootDir = new File('').toPath().toString()

include ':exoplayer:library'
include ':exoplayer:library'
include ':exoplayer:library-core'
include ':exoplayer:library-dash'
include ':exoplayer:library-hls'
include ':exoplayer:library-smoothstreaming'
include ':exoplayer:library-ui'
include ':exoplayer:extension-okhttp'

project(modulePrefix + 'library').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 
'library/all')
project(modulePrefix + 'library-core').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 
'library/core')
project(modulePrefix + 'library-dash').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 
'library/dash')
project(modulePrefix + 'library-hls').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 
'library/hls')
project(modulePrefix + 'library-smoothstreaming').projectDir = new 
File(rootDir, 'library/smoothstreaming')
project(modulePrefix + 'library-ui').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 
'library/ui')
project(modulePrefix + 'extension-okhttp').projectDir = new 
File(rootDir, 'extensions/okhttp')
```

Now I add the dependencies of the exoplayer libs in my `build.gradle` like this

```
implementation project(':exoplayer-library-core')
implementation project(':exoplayer-library-dash')
implementation project(':exoplayer-library-hls')
implementation project(':exoplayer-library-smoothstreaming')
implementation project(':exoplayer-library-ui')
implementation project(':exoplayer-extension-okhttp')
```

and I get this error

```
Project with path ':exoplayer-library-core' could not be found in root 
project 'myProject'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing that:

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'main'

include 'changelogs'
include 'common'

project(':changelogs').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../changelogs')
project(':common').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../common')
```

And Build.gradle

```
implementation project(':changelogs')
```